# Asp.Net Application Database Connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

When I try to write in C# a connection to my app to my database, I build the application successfully in Visual Studio 2005 but when I run the site in debugger i get an error:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 118.
```

Here is the connection code that is giving the error:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server"].ConnectionString);
```

I have the connection string written correctly in my web.config, file so im clueless on what this remotely means. Im not sure if im missing anything. Any help appreciated. Here is my entire code for the section that might help:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class RateAnalyzerPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string IDnumber = mechantNumber.Text;
        string selectSQL = "SELECT FROM Authors Where MID='"+ IDnumber +"'";
   // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server="); 
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            QualVol.Text = reader["TotalVolume"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Let me know if im missing some data that would help.

Heres the connection string:

Comment: What line gives the error, when you open the connection? Could you post your web.config connectionStrings section?

Comment: You'll need to post the `connectionStrings` section of your .config file; that's where the error most likely is

Comment: `code`<connectionStrings>
 <add name="Server" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Odata;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=&quot;Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio&quot;User ID=Name;Password=PW" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings> `code`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've separated out and XML decoded the connection string value:

```
Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Odata;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"User ID=Name;Password=PW
```

As you can see, you're missing a `;` between `Application Name` and `User ID`. I'm not sure if that's *the* issue, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string use the `Integrated Security=True`, but the right syntax is 
`Integrated Security=SSPI;` or `Trusted_Connection=True` so change it and remove the UserId and Password.
(or remove Integrated Security=True and leave UserID and Password)

Try to change something in your code.

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string IDnumber = mechantNumber.Text; 
    string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM Authors Where MID=@num"; 
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
                      (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                       ["Server"].ConnectionString))
    {
         SqlDataReader reader; 
         con.Open(); 
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con); 
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", IDNumber);
         reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
         while (reader.Read()) 
         { 
              QualVol.Text = reader["TotalVolume"].ToString(); 
         } 
         reader.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

Try to use the `using` statemend, this guarantees the disposing of your connection
Try to use parametrized query, this avoid Sql Injection attacks and quoting problems
Also SELECT requires a fields list or `*`

Comment: Was a quick change :P I meant Server.

Comment: Updated answer with IntegratedSecurity=True and UserID/Password.

Answer (score 2):

I think Jacob has it right.  On a side note, don't do this:

```
string selectSQL = "SELECT FROM Authors Where MID='"+ IDnumber +"'";
```

This will lead to sql injection attacks, just like the one that was used to get yahoo user accounts last week.

Do this instead:

```
 string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM Authors Where MID=@ID"; 
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", IDnumber );
```